# How to Enable push rules in Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/push_rules/push_rules.html) push rules are not visible under :

`Settings > Repository` and expand `Push Rules`

How to enable push rules [my gitlab repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyvBd.png)

Comment: Are you Owner or Maintainer of your repository ? Because following the gitlab [permissions] (https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/permissions.html]) only Owner or Maintainer can manage push rules.

Answer (score 6):

Push Rules is only visible if you are **Maintainer** of project. Also, Push Rules are only available if You not use Free plan. 
**Settings** > **Repository** > **Upgrade your plan**

[image]

Comment: I logged in as a master. But still is not showing the push rules actually I used the community edition

Comment: Yes. I am maintainer

Comment: Push Rules are available if you bought a plan:
https://ibb.co/NKmNJ9P
https://ibb.co/DGYCpsz